# C# Lockbits for more exotic PixelFormats

Tags: c#, pixelformat, lockbits

I'm writing a performance critical class in C# for image manipulation. I'm using LockBits to gain access to the actual data directly and all is working well but I'd like to get more info on the memory signature of certain PixelFormats, most notably Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb.

Anyone know a reliable website somewhere which lists these?

Answer (score 2):

You will find neccessary information about image manipulation with using LockBits.

**https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx**